# Do contraction semigroups inherit some properties of their infinitesimal generator?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, semigroup-of-operators

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $\{S(t)\}_{t\ge 0}$ be a contraction semigroup. Also, let $A$ be the infinitesimal generator of the semigroup $\{S(t)\}_{t\ge 0}$ and $K$ is the kernel of $A$. My questions are as follows.

1. If $Ah \in K^\perp$ for all $h \in H$, then $S(t)h \in K^\perp$ for all $h\in H$? (where $K^\perp$ is its orthogonal complement of $K$.)
2. If a certain subset $K \subset H$ is invariant for $A$, then $K$ is also invariant for $S(t)$? In other words, if $A(K) \subset K$, then $S(t)(K) \subset K$?

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: @Shaun Thanks for pointing it out. That's a good point. Actually I also wanted to be more specific, but since I have two questions, I didn't have any idea but a general one. However, after thinking hard, I've come up with an appropriate title.

Comment: For 1. consider $A=0\lvert_{K}\oplus -\Bbb1\lvert_{K^\perp}$ where $K$ is some subspace of $H$. Then $S(t) = \Bbb1\lvert_{K}\oplus e^{-t}\lvert_{K^\perp}$, clearly the image of $S(t)$ no longer is $K^\perp$. For 2. you seem to be assuming that $A$ is bounded, so $S(t)=\exp(t A)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{t^nA^n}{n!}$, from which it is obvious that _closed_ invariant subspaces of $A$ are also invariant under $S(t)$.